# Como se chama estas instruções no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Como é chamado as instruções em PHP específicas para o Wordpress? Do tipo:

```
bloginfo("url");

bloginfo("template_url");

get_bloginfo("description", "display");
```

Tentei buscar por **features** mas não é isso !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez você esteja procurando por está página, [**Referência de Funções**](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Refer%C3%AAncia_de_Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es).

Veja também [PHP Documentation Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/).

Comment: ***Function Reference*** isso aê !!!

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Dê uma olhada nessa [página](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=php&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-class&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-method) também.